# Scraping a range of news articles with Beautiful Soup - issue with showing all articels. Full code below

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

#Importing libraries:

```
import html5lib
import nltk
from newspaper import Article
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import numpy as np
# select a url of any news article
url = 'https://www.standaard.be/nieuws/meest-recent'
article = Article(url)
```

#setting up beautiful soup requirements:

```
article.download()
article.parse()
nltk.download('punkt')
article.nlp()


r1 = requests.get(url)
coverpage = r1.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(coverpage, 'html5lib')

coverpage_news = soup.find_all('a', class_='link-live')
n_articles = 150
```

#testing for loop. Everything works fine up until here.

```
for i in np.arange(0, n_articles):
    link = coverpage_news[i]['href']
    print (link)

nr_articles = len(link)+1
nr_articles
```

#Should be all coming together:
Each of the sections do what they're supposed to do, but somehow the for-loop doesn't seem to extract article-titles one-by-one. Should I nest another loop in the exisiting for-loop? Any help would be highly appreciated!

```
# Scraping all articles
number_of_articles = nr_articles 
# Empty lists for content, links and titles
news_contents = []
list_links = []
list_titles = []

    
for n in np.arange(0, number_of_articles):
    
    # Getting the link of the article
    link = coverpage_news[n]['href']
    list_links.append(link)   
    
    # Getting the title
    article = requests.get(link)
    article_content = article.content
    soup_article = BeautifulSoup(article_content, 'html5lib')    
    title = soup_article.find_all('header', class_='article__header')
    y = title[0].find_all('h1')
    list_titles.append(y)  
    
    
    # Reading the content (it is divided in paragraphs)
    article = requests.get(link)
    article_content = article.content
    soup_article = BeautifulSoup(article_content, 'html5lib')
    body = soup_article.find_all('div', class_='article__body')
    x = body[0].find_all('p')


    
    # Unifying the paragraphs
    list_paragraphs = []
    for p in np.arange(0, len(x)):
        paragraph = x[p].get_text()
        list_paragraphs.append(paragraph)
        final_article = " ".join(list_paragraphs)
        
    news_contents.append(final_article)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### What happens?

1. Your grabbing all the links and define `n_articles = 150`
2. Then you try to assign `number_of_articles = nr_articles` but `nr_articles` is not defined.

### Solution

Change `n_articles = 150` to `nr_articles = 150`

**Example**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import numpy as np
# select a url of any news article
url = 'https://www.standaard.be/nieuws/meest-recent'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'lxml')
coverpage_news = soup.find_all('a', class_='link-live')
nr_articles = 3
number_of_articles = nr_articles 

# Empty lists for content, links and titles
news_contents = []
list_links = []
list_titles = []

for n in np.arange(0, number_of_articles):

    link = coverpage_news[n]['href']
    list_links.append(link)   
    
    # Getting the contents
    article = requests.get(link)
    article_content = article.content
    soup_article = BeautifulSoup(article_content, 'html5lib')    
    
    list_titles.append(soup_article.select_one('header.article__header > h1').get_text())  

    news_contents.append(''.join([p.get_text() for p in soup_article.select('div.article__body p')]))

list_titles
```

**Output**

```
['Van Gucht tempert paniek over Britse variant: ‘Virus in geheel blijven bestrijden’',
 'Advies experten: ‘Laat kinderen vanaf tien jaar mondmasker dragen op publieke plaatsen’',
 'Parket opent onderzoek naar perslekken in de zaak-Kucam']
```

Comment: will pay attention adding examples. Thanks, it works.